# Natural Language Processing(syntatctic,semantic,progmatic) Analysis

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp

My text contains text=**"Ravi beated Ragu"**

My Question will be **"Who beated Ragu?"**

The Answer Should come **"Ravi"** Using NLP

How to do this by natural language processing.
Kindly guide me to proceed with this by syntactic,semantic and progmatic analysis using python

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should read an introductory book on NLP to be familiar with the chain processes you are trying to achieve. You are trying to do question-answering , aren't you? If it is the case, you should read about question-answering systems. The above sentence has to be morphologically analyzed (so read about morphological analyzers), syntactically parsed (so read about syntactic parsing) and semantically understood (so read about anaphora resolution and , in linguistics, theta theory). `Ravi` is called `agent` and `Ragu` is called `patient` or `experiencer`. Only then, you can proceed to pursue your objectives.

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You need lots of data.

What you are looking for might be reading comprehension, thus I recommend you read the papers(for instance: [Reading Comprehension on the SQuAD Dataset](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/reports/2762006.pdf)) by the competitors from [SQuAD](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/).

For simple tasks(implying limited generalization) and if you don't have such large size corpus, you can use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) by manually writing some rules.